# Система контроля версий. Offline-альтернатива

Tags: visual-studio, контроль-версий

Есть ли offline локальная система контроля версий, подобная `Git`? Пишу в `VS-2017`.

Я сейчас просто работаю в такой компании, где стоит `CheckPoint`, запрещающий доступ к определенным Web-ресурсам, включая `Git` (сам сайт github работает, но коммиты, гитклоны и все остальное не работает).

P.S. это не АйТи контора. Конечно, можно попробовать запросить доступ к Git, но здесь это очень геморно, потрачу много сил, нервов и времени

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git прекрасно работает офлайн.

Вместо удаленного репозитория можно использовать обычную папку - по сути просто еще одну копию репозитория: [How to add a local repo and treat it as a remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603750/2752075)

```
git remote add origin /бла/бла/репозиторий/.git
```

---

Либо можно вообще не хранить удаленные копии репозитория (отказаться от `push`, `pull`, `fetch` и подобных команд), хотя это более рискованно.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, добавить в ответ, как при таком подходе пушить, например?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko По идее так же, как и обычно.

Comment: Ок, я сейчас попробую. Если все будет ок, отмечу ответ галочкой

Comment: Да все верно, мало того можно обмениваться кодом минуя единую точку синхронизации в виде гит сервера

Answer (score 5):

Есть. Эта система называется Git :) ставьте гит, фиксируйте изменения в локальном репозитории, просто не пушите изменения на сервер. Ну и более чем реально поднять собственный git или svn сервер. Если есть оборудование, способное закрывать определенные сайты, думается в компании найдется хоть один компьютер, который можно никогда не выключать и использовать как сервер